# Find html content and write into variable

Tags: swift, xcode

I started with an easy project to learn more about swift and Xcode.

I worked out to write at least the first div-tag into a variable called element. Now I want to put a text (the 9,62) which is always in this class of the website

```
    <span 

    class="Trsdu(0.3s) Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(b)" 

    data-reactid="20">9.62</span>
```

Would be great if you can give me some code how to get that text into a variable so that i can print it on the UILabel.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var textlabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let myUrlString = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/LEO.DE?p=LEO.DE.tsrc=fin-srch"
        guard let myURL = URL(string: myUrlString) else { return }

        do{
    let myHtmlString = try String(contentsOf: myURL, encoding: .utf8)
    let htmlContent = myHtmlString

    do {
        let doc = try SwiftSoup.parse(htmlContent)

        do {
            let element = try doc.select("div").first()
                print(element)
            do {
                let text = try element?.text()
                textlabel.text = text
            }
        } catch {

        } catch {

        }

    }
} catch let error {
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: Hint: you do not need a new do/catch for each function call that might throw an error so one pair of do/catch is enough. You would only need more than one if different errors thrown requires different actions

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage the power of SwiftSoup and use this simple solution:

```
let className = "Trsdu(0.3s) Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(b)"
let span = try doc.getElementsByClass(className)
let value = try span.text()
textLabel.text = value
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: @Hascins You're welcome! If this answer helped you, you could upvote it, or accept it by ticking the checkmark next to it. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).